# Terminal MacOS Fastlane/Gym/xcodebuild Error 65: GenerateDSYMFile, dsymutil malloc: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: fastlane, dsymutil

I'm trying to make an little bash script for automatisation of ipa uploading on itunes. [From Xcode uploading it works fine].
For command:

```
gym
```

from Fastlane,some projects are uploading fine, others are failing with log:

```
The following build commands failed:    
GenerateDSYMFile [...] 
    Exit status: 65
```

In gym logs:

```
GenerateDSYMFile [...] 
dsymutil(20223,0x7fff724c3000) malloc: *** error for object 0x610000100000: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil failed with exit code 6
```

...tried all google solutions....

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue.

I've found a reference in [this thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18311),  and also [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/embree-photo-realistic-ray-tracing-kernels/topic/584117)

suggesting that it's the **MallocNanoZone** environment variable. after changing it (on terminal):

> export MallocNanoZone=0

The build successfully completed.